# How to pass/concat variable into the `data.aws_ami` section in the `aws_instance` resource

Tags: variables, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am having difficulties with defining a variable inside the `ami=data.aws_ami.$var.ami_name.id` line.

I have tried `ami= "${data.aws_ami.(var.ami_name).id}"`but in both cases I am getting the:

```
79:   ami = data.aws_ami.(var.ami_name)).id
│ 
│ An attribute name is required after a dot.
```

It only works with the string value `data.aws_ami.ubuntu-1804.id`.

My question is how to concat the variable to the `data.aws_ami`?

The end goal is to provision based on different OS ec2 instances (Suse,Ubuntu,RHEL) All depending on the variable provided when deploying it.

```
variable "ami_name" {
  default = "ubuntu"
}

data "aws_ami" "amazon" {
  most_recent = true
  owners      = ["amazon"]
  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["amzn2-ami-hvm*"]
  }
}

data "aws_ami" "ubuntu" {
  most_recent = true
  owners      = ["099720109477"] # Canonical
  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-server-*"]
  }
  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "linux" {
  key_name = var.ami_key_pair_name
  //ami           = var.ami_id
  //I want this to be dynamic so I can deploy either Amazon or Ubuntu in all regions. 
  ami            = data.aws_ami.$var.ami_name.id 
  //ami           = data.aws_ami.ubuntu.id # this works
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
tags = {
    Name = var.instance_name
  }
  vpc_security_group_ids = [
    aws_security_group.allow-ssh-http.id
  ]
}
```

I did the search but could not find anything related. I am using `Terraform v0.15.4`

Comment: Please add the `data.aws_ami` to the question and specify the differences among them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you show: `data.aws_ami.$var.ami_name.id` that is not valid terraform syntax.

Here is a possibility for what you are asking:

```
provider "aws" { region = "us-east-2" }

locals {
    allowed_os = {
        "amazon": {owner: "amazon",       filter: "amzn2-ami-hvm*"},
        "suse":   {owner: "amazon",       filter: "*suse*"},
        "RHEL":   {owner: "amazon",       filter: "*RHEL*"},
        "ubuntu": {owner: "099720109477", filter: "*ubuntu-bionic-18.04-amd64-*"},
    }
}

variable "ami_name" {
  default = "ubuntu"

  validation {
    condition     = can(regex("amazon|suse|RHEL|ubuntu", var.ami_name))
    error_message = "Invalid ami name, allowed_values = [amazon suse RHEL ubuntu]."
  }
}

data "aws_ami" "os" {
  for_each = local.allowed_os

  most_recent = true
  owners      = [each.value.owner]
  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = [each.value.filter]
  }
}

resource "aws_instance" "linux" {
  ami           = data.aws_ami.os[var.ami_name].id
  instance_type = "t2.micro"
  # ... todo add arguments here
}
```

My approach here is to use a `for_each` in the aws_ami, that will give us an array, we can consume that later in the aws_instance resource:

- `data.aws_ami.os["ubuntu"].id`
  Here we use a hardcoded value to access a specific AMI in your code.
- `data.aws_ami.os[var.ami_name].id`
  Or this way with the variable that will be provided by user or a config file.

You can add more items to the array to add other operating systems, and same with the filters, you can just change the `allowed_os` local variable to suit your needs.

As an extra, I added validation to your `ami_name` variable to match the allowed different OS we use in the for_each, that way we prevent any issues right before they can cause errors.

Comment: thanks for your help. unfortunately, that did not work for me. Still trying to get my head around how would that work for different OS if the owners is "amazon". How would I relate your code to the default  `data "aws_ami" "ubuntu"{}` with values pointing to the latest image?

Comment: @greenszpila your question was not very detailed to start with ... you have no code for a `aws_ami` maybe clarify all that and we can revisit this... Do you have any experience with arrays in terraform? Did you run a plan with my example?

Comment: thanks for getting back to me.  I would like to have one deployment and depending on variable specified in the `ami`  line within `resource` section. This would deploy either ubuntu, amazon, rhel based ec2 instance. The command I use is terraform apply -var-file=ubuntu.tf for ubuntu image and so on. I have added both `aws_ami` section to the code above. No I don't have experience with arrays in tf and when I run plan with your example I have got UEFI related strange errors. Thank you.

Comment: @greenszpila I updated my code to follow what you are doing on your aws_ami

Comment: thanks @HelderSepulveda, that has worked, really appreciate it. thanks so much!